# iPhone CGContext: drawing line with two different colors

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I want to draw a line with different colors using CGContext.

This is my code

```
   CGSize size = CGSizeMake(200, 200);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 1, 1);

    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 50, 50);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 100, 50);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 200, 100);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

I am trying this code, its returns error:

```
<Error>: CGContextAddLineToPoint: no current point.
```

Comment: Before you start the new path you can get the current point using `CGPathGetCurrentPoint` and use that to start off the new path

Comment: I am not sure what your question is, but isn't just a moveToPoint: missing after you started the second path...

Comment: Thanks @Volker. When i started the second path, i added moveToPoint: in my code. Its working fine.

Comment: @user1831389 David's solution seems even better...

Answer (score 2):

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextClearRect(context, rect);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);

CGContextBeginPath(context);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 1, 1);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 100, 100);
CGContextStrokePath(context); // and draw blue line

CGContextBeginPath(context);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 100, 100);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 200, 100);     
CGContextStrokePath(context); // draw red line
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code maybe help you:

```
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(200, 200);
//UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0); //comment this line,  if you want a image, see bottom two line.
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);

CGContextBeginPath(context);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 1, 1);   //MoveToPoint First
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 50, 50);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 100, 50);
CGContextStrokePath(context);

CGContextBeginPath(context);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 100, 50);   //MoveToPoint First
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 200, 100);
CGContextStrokePath(context);

//UIImage* resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); //if you just need a image
//UIGraphicsEndImageContext(); //match UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions, if need a image
```